# Activate function on window resize

Tags: javascript

So I have a slideshow with pictures that I don't want to be shown on devices with a pixel width less than 1080px. which it does sometimes.

this is the site: https://82729.ict-lab.nl/SnakesAreFish/index.html (it's about the 'screenshots' section)

```
  <script>
    function showSlides() {
        if (window.innerWidth > 1080) {
            var slideIndex = 0;
            showSlides();

            function showSlides() {
                var i;
                var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

                for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
                }
                slideIndex++;
                if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
                    slideIndex = 1
                }
                slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                setTimeout(showSlides, 8000);
                }
            }
        }

      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        showSlides();
      });

      window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        showSlides();
      });
    </script>
```

I expect the function to activate when you resize from a widescreen to 1080px or less the slides disappear, but they don't.
They do disappear however when you refresh within or visit the site on a screen of 1080px.

Comment: why are you redefining the method inside the method? Problem is if it starts out > 1080 and you resize, it is already running.... so just set a check inside to not run when a variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the redeclaration of `showSlides` and you should be fine

```
function showSlides() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1080) return;

    let slideIndex = 0;
    const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++; 

    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }

    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        setTimeout(showSlides, 8000);
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I implemented this but now it no longer shows the images?

Answer (score 0):

Add logic in it that kills the interval when the size changes below the threshold.

```js
var updateShow = (function () {

  var slideshowTimer = null
  var slideIndex = -1
  
  return function () {
  
     var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
     if(!slides.length) return

    // If width is greater and not running, start it
    if (window.innerWidth > 10/*1080*/) {
      if (!slideshowTimer) {
        slideshowTimer = window.setInterval(executeIt, 1000)
      }
    } else {
      window.clearInterval(slideshowTimer)
      slideshowTimer = null
    }

    function executeIt() {
      if (slideIndex!==-1) {
         slides[slideIndex].style.display = "none";
      }
      slideIndex++
      if (slideIndex >= slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 0
      }
      slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
})();

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  updateShow();
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  updateShow();
});
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/300" class="mySlides" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" class="mySlides" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" class="mySlides" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/300" class="mySlides" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work and i don't know why but I uploaded this and now it doesn't show the images anymore

Comment: I added the slides into it, not sure what your issue was.